# Change position of lines drawing on html5 canvas using createjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

I have slot game with five lines using Createjs but I want to add more line to this game.I am able to add more line successfully but not able to change position of lines. Please see image(https://ibb.co/nnnctF). The code that creating line is below.

```
   //LINE 1 
    var oBut = new CBetBut( 334 + oSprite.width/2, 282 + oSprite.height/2,oSprite,true);
    oBut.addEventListenerWithParams(ON_MOUSE_UP, this._onBetLineClicked, this,1);
    _aLinesBut[0] = oBut;

    //LINE 2
    oBut = new CBetBut( 334 + oSprite.width/2, 180 + oSprite.height/2,oSprite,true);
    oBut.addEventListenerWithParams(ON_MOUSE_UP, this._onBetLineClicked, this,2);
    _aLinesBut[1] = oBut;

    //LINE 3
    oBut = new CBetBut( 334 + oSprite.width/2, 432 + (oSprite.height/2),oSprite,true);
    oBut.addEventListenerWithParams(ON_MOUSE_UP, this._onBetLineClicked, this,3);
    _aLinesBut[2] = oBut;
```

I have tried by changing values in above lines but nothing happens.Can Anybody please guide me How can I change the line's position. ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell how exactly you are drawing lines based on your above code (eg, what is CBetBut?).

If you are using Graphics, you can save off individual commands, and then modify them later. For example:

```
var g = new createjs.Graphics();
g.beginStroke("red").setStrokeStyle(3).moveTo(0,0);
var p1 = g.lineTo(10,10).command;
var p2 = g.lineTo(20,20).command;
// Later
p1.y = 20;
p2.y = 10;
```

Hope that helps. You can read more on the CreateJS blog. http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/